# How to decrease the speed of custom ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have implemented a custom progress bar and I am displaying it while getting data from an URL, it is working fine as progress bar is spinning, but my problem is that I am not able to find a proper way to decrease its revolving speed, currently it is spinning very fast.

please help me with your suggestions and reply.

xml layout for progress bar:-

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/showProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate" />
```

Also here's "my_progress_indeterminate" which is used to rotate my custom progressbar :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_loading"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

please share some example if possible to decrease the speed of rotation.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It will help you.

Create progressbar_custom.xml

`/res/drawable/progressbar_custom.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadius="18dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="5dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dp"
            android:width="48dp" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#802A67AD"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="#ff2A67AD"
            android:startColor="#002A67AD"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Add Progressbar in XML files

```
 <ProgressBar
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_custom" />
```

Answer (score 6):

add in code to progress.xml

```
android:fromDegrees="0"

android:toDegrees="1080"   <!-- Add in code to progress custumize xml to speed up -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "rotate" instead of "animated-rotate" and changing android:toDegrees or android:toDegress should make it go slower.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_loading"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```